# Getting value from checkbox onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, onchange

I have a simple toggle checkbox feature that goes over product packages to select them. I created this in an input checkbox fashion to be able to capture the value. What I do not understand is how to capture the value for when only the checkbox is showing.

I know to capture the value I would do this:

`$('#package2').val();`

But how do I only get the value when it is 'activated'/'selected'. Then once it is selected and I have the value I am wanting to display it next to where it says 'Product Chosen'.

Also, you can see in the snippet or fiddle that when you click on both boxes and then click a box again to unselect it, that the "Proceed" goes away. Is there also a way to keep that showing for whenever any of the boxes are checked?

[Here is a jsfiddle as well.](https://jsfiddle.net/r1cn6ty6/)

```js
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').show('200');
        $('#next1').show();
      } else {
        $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').hide('200');
        $('#next1').hide();
      }
});
```

```css
.package-img {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
    position: relative;
}
#calendar-wrap, #tp-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.checkmark-img {
    display: none;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.proceed-btn {
    display: none;
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
.calendar-check {
  display: none;
}

.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-container">
  <div id="calendar-wrap" class="product-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
    <label for="package1" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src="images/calendar-package.png" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img">
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package1" value="Photo Gift">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div id="tp-wrap" class="product-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
    <label for="package2" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src="images/tp-package.png" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="tp-img">
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package2" value="Touch Points">
  </div>
</div>
Product chosen
<div class="proceed-btn" id="next1">PROCEED</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool){
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(1000) : this.fadeOut(1000);
}
$(function() {
  $('.calendar-check').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').toggle(this.checked);
//        $('#next1').toggle($('.calendar-check:checked').length > 0);
    $('#next1').fadeBoolToggle($('.calendar-check:checked').length > 0);
    var prods = [];
    $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() { prods.push($(this).val()) });
    $("#prods").html("Product"+
                     (prods.length==1?"":"s")+
                     " chosen: "+prods.join(", ")
                    );
  });
});
```

```css
.package-img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  position: relative;
}
#calendar-wrap,
#tp-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.proceed-btn {
  display: none;
//*  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;*/
}
.calendar-check {
  display: none;
}
.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-container">
  <div id="calendar-wrap" class="product-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
    <label for="package1" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src="images/calendar-package.png" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img">
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package1" value="Photo Gift">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div id="tp-wrap" class="product-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
    <label for="package2" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src="images/tp-package.png" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="tp-img">
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package2" value="Touch Points">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="prods">Products chosen</div>
<div class="proceed-btn" id="next1">PROCEED</div>
```

Comment: I am wanting to get the value from the checkbox inputs and just display them below my boxes. `$('#package2').val();`. Then if you run the snippet and see when both boxes are checked, click on one again, you will see the onchange event makes the proceed button disappear. So essentially, if you decide to go with both packages and then remove one before proceeding the button goes away.

Comment: Regarding the proceed button, if any box is active (checked), I am wanting the proceed button to stay active as well. Not sure how to do that, as well as writing the value for the checkbox input.

Comment: This always keeps the proceed button showing once something is clicked on.

Comment: I did, but if you click on one and activate it, if you then check it again to unselect it, the button still stays active.

Comment: Try the code I updated. The proceed will disappear if there are no checked boxes assuming the selector is correct

Comment: It still is showing the proceed without anything selected.

Comment: Great, thanks! How can I add a fade to the toggle in this format though? I tried `.toggle(this.checked, '100');` and then `.fadeToggle(this.checked, '100');`, but neither method worked.

Comment: I added a fade, but had to remove the transition from the CSS

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for all of your help!